# American refusal of the IPA: why?

Tags: american-english, dictionaries, phonology, phonetics, ipa

Are there any historical or political reasons for the rather consistent refusal of the International Phonetic Alphabet on the part of American academics?

Did Mark Twain's home-made-English-spelling-centred phonetic rendering of regional pronunciations set a trend?

Comment: "Americans academics" do not reject the IPA - I learned it in college in the 1960s. Most American *dictionary publishers* don't employ it, probably because few linguists buy mass-market dictionaries, and everybody else is perfectly happy with what they've got.

Comment: Precisely. Webster's pre-steampunk notation system is the one that nobody ever understands or learns, because it makes no sense. Therefore it's perfect for an American dictionary. Merriam-Webster has published Kenyon & Knott's _Pronouncing Dictionary of American English,_ with excellent IPA-based phonemic notation, since the 1950s, but they continue to not use it anywhere else, for fear Americans might learn something. It's like the metric system; "not invented here".

Comment: Therefore the rule I suggest to any English learner: DON'T buy a monolingual English dictionary published in the United States. Make sure that the English pronunciations are in IPA; if you see anything else, don't trust the book.

Comment: @John, StoneyB: I'm comparatively ignorant in such matters, obviously. But surely if IPA is an *international* symbol set, it must include many sounds that don't even occur in spoken AmE? And perhaps others where different speakers do indeed pronounce certain sounds differently because of regional accents, but those differences are consistent, and known to the natives. So in the context of a "pronouncing dictionary", they only need to know *this is sound **X*** (unlike *you*, John, they don't usually need to know about dialectal variations in how "sound X" is actually articulated).

Comment: It's the same reason that nobody uses Dvorak keyboards. They're more efficient, but you'd have to learn a new system and as long as all the keyboards are qwerty, there's no point.

Comment: @Peter: Is it necessarily the case that Dvorak keyboards are more efficient? I always thought the most efficient text input device (ignoring speech recognition and up-and-coming "brain wave detection" devices) would be something based around detecting twitches of the fingers on one hand. (Something better than a mobile phone, I mean! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, the Dvorak is provably more efficient (the QWERTY was designed to be slightly inefficient to work around physical limitations of early typewriters. Dvorak does not have that limitation) If you can invent an efficient 'twitch' based input device many people will be interested, but you'll have to beat inertia to get folks off their QWERTY's...

Comment: @Rory: I read about one such device some years ago, where it was claimed that after a few hours one could enter text with it faster than a standard k/b. You've only got to look at what even relative novices can do on a guitar fretboard to see there should be a real market there. But hey! Here we are in 2014 still married to MS Windows because nobody wants the upheaval of switching to a simpler implementation of an OS more suited to today's hardware, software, and user requirements. Innovation lures, but inertia rules.

Comment: @Fumble, there are implementations of IPA that work very well for that as well (just look at any pronunciation hint given on Wikipedia, for example—or any Oxford dictionary, for that matter). IPA comes in varying degrees of broad- and fineness, and for dictionary purposes, broad IPA for English would be so much more efficient than Webster Spaghetti.

Comment: @Janus: I can't see anything simple enough for me on the [Wikipedia IPA page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). I keep a browser link to [this little table](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm), but I'm not entirely sure it's exactly the same as whatever anyone else uses when they post things in IPA notation here, so I'm a bit leery of using it much.

Comment: Concerning the Twain reference: I was taught never to use stylistic misspelling unless the narrator would actually have been ignorant enough to spell the word that way. Mark Twain was cited as an example of a writer who did this well, and it was pointed out that stylistic misspellings in Twain's writings are rarer than most readers believe. On the other hand, the earlier author James Fenimore Cooper was cited as one of the first to experiment with phonetic misspellings, and it was claimed that he used them too freely.

Comment: But as you can probably infer from my use of the passive voice, I have no reference for any of this.

Comment: @Fumble, would you say the [US dictionary transcription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:United_States_dictionary_transcription) is any simpler? That to me is much more complex, and completely impossible to find your way around. Things like /hə·wī′·-ē/ just look completely foreign to me. Say I don’t know how to pronounce the _oo_ in ‘boorish’. In USDT, that’s /bŏŏr′·ĭsh/, which certainly doesn’t tell me anything without looking it up. /'bʊriʃ/ at least tells me (with the merest scrap of IPA knowledge) that the vowel is _short_, which is probably what I wanted to know to begin with.

Comment: @Janus: except that when you're using IPA for American English, people often leave out the length marks because length is not phonemic in American English vowels. And it's /ˈbʊərɪʃ/ in some dictionaries, which is a diphthong (which it probably isn't for most Americans).

Comment: @Peter, I've mostly seen people leaving out length marks when using IPA to write English _phonemically_, which isn't usually what dictionaries do. I agree that IPA is perhaps not the best tool to write English phonemically (but USDT is certainly no great shakes either), but for phonetic notation, compatibility with the rest of the world seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @Janus: I more or less agree with you, because compatibility is a very good thing (even though I don't think IPA is any simpler than US dictionary transcription). One point: growing up speaking American English, when I first saw the phonetic length marks in IPA for British English, they seemed completely nonsensical to me, because American English doesn't have long and short vowels the way British English does. They don't belong in American IPA dictionaries.

Comment: @Peter: Sure it does! Phonetically, the vowels in ‘pull’ and ‘pool’ are different both in quantity and length, as are those in ‘hit/heat’, and even (to a lesser degree) ‘bat/bad’, etc. Only phonemically is there no length distinction (or, alternatively, no tense/lax distinction).

Comment: @Janus: I probably said that badly. When I talk, the vowel in /bæd/ is longer than the vowel in /biːt/, and around the same length as the vowel in /biːd/. This confused me; if you're going to use British length marks for American English, it's not useful at all. And if you a different system of length marks, you confuse nearly everybody.

Comment: @Peter, this is true. It's true of BrE as well, though, and I would personally, in a phonetic transcription, write /bæ:d/, though I know the standard convention is not to do so.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I read in a very interesting book about the factors which can speed up or slow down the spread of innovation ('Guns, Germs, and Steel' by a UCLA geographer, Jared Diamond) that the reason for QWERTY keyboards was precisely to slow down secretaries, otherwise, the 'arms' of the – initially – mechanical typewriters threatened to jam.

Comment: And I read in a book that someone who had developed a non-QWERTY typewriter and a QWERTY typist had a typing race, which the QWERTY typist won because he could touch-type, so it was commonly accepted thereafter that QWERTY was better. (I left the book in my other country, so I'm afraid I can't tell you the name).

Comment: I learned the American system of phonetic notation first, and really didn't care for IPA.  But there came a time, in the 80s I think, when I had to start using IPA in my classes, because linguistics articles and textbooks were all using IPA.  IPA has been standard in American academic linguistics for a long time now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A few years late ! but (a subset of) IPA can be used for phonemic representation (ie. just the sounds present in a particular language) while the full set allows reasonably accurate phonetic transcription (ie of the sounds in any language). You can see a bizarre example of this on Wiktionary where someone has provided both a phonemic transcription and then unnecessarily detailed phonetic transcriptions of "thrill": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrill

Comment: I've just come across your question (never too late!) You might find this paper of some interest: [Noah Webster and the standardization of sound](https://doi.org/10.4000/erea.6096).

Comment: @PeterShor "length is not phonemic in American English vowels" What do you mean? Length is not phonemic in British English vowels either. English vowels, in both British and American English, have qualities so different that length is decidedly redundant to note to begin with. Now compare to a language like Japanese, where vowel quality remains mostly unchanged in both short and long vowels, then length notation is warranted. There is no such thing as a long [ɪ:] sound in English, and the "short" /i/ used in some dictionaries is underdefined, variously realized by speakers as [ɪ] or [i].

Comment: @PeterShor "because American English doesn't have long and short vowels the way British English does" I'd recommend you check A Course in Phonetics by Peter Ladefoged & Keith Johnson. You seem to have an inadequate understanding on the term "phonemic". The book has a chapter that explains precisely this problem, and just to sum it up, it's all about convention. It's not because American vowels are somehow different from British vowels in terms of phonemic length. There is nothing phonemic about preferring /ɑ/ over /ɑː/, these sounds do not contrast in either British or American English.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw: If you read my comments carefully, I never claimed that there was an English phoneme /ɑ/. In modern Southern British English, the main difference between the vowels of *bared* and *bed* is vowel length. This is why [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bare) represents them phonetically as /bɛːd/ and /bɛd/. And while there is no phoneme /ɑ/ in English, one of the clues that British speakers use to distinguish /ɑː/ from /ɒ/ and from /ʌ/ is vowel length. This is why British dictionaries put length marks on the vowels, they're not (as you seem to think) just for decoration.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw: If you think vowel length is not phonemic in British English, either explain the difference in vowel quality in modern Southern British English between *bared* and *bed* or prove that British English speakers cannot distinguish these two words.

Comment: @PeterShor It's not what I think. It's a fact in both Received Pronunciation and General American that there length is not phonemic. To claim that length is phonemic, you'll have to prove that ONLY length causes contrast, which is why I said there is no such contrast between /ɑ/ and /ɑː/, or /ɪ/ and /i/. That's what's "phonemic" means. /ɑː/ and /ɒ/ do not contrast in length, but in vowel quality: tongue position, lip roundedness > the vowel sounds different, not just longer or shorter than the other. Length is phonetic. This isn't my opinion, it's explained in *A Course in Phonetics*.

Comment: @PeterShor "This is why Lexico represents them phonetically as /bɛːd/ and /bɛd/" This is only proof that even though British dictionaries are unified in using the IPA, there are just two many different **conventions**. The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary transcribes <bare> as /beə/, and does not recognize such sound as /ɛː/ in Received Pronunciation. There is also the temptation to describe slight *phonetic* or *dialectal* nuances too. I do find it frustrating that the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dicationry and the LPD explicitly transcribes the American tapped t, while most others do not.

Comment: @PeterShor Interestingly enough, I don't think I've ever seen any dictionary uses the letter ɛ. The LPD uses e. Whatever character set that the dictionary makers use also causes confusion. You do have to take a lot of these "pronunciation guide" with a grain of salt. Don't just rely on the "phonemic" transcriptions. 10 different phonologists will probably use 5 different systems or 8 different letter sets.

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry, I meant "too many" not "two many".

Comment: @PeterShor "one of the clues that British speakers use to distinguish /ɑː/ from /ɒ/ and from /ʌ/ is vowel length" This is quite a bold claim. I wonder what psychological experiment you've done that proves British speakers literally use vowel length as a "clue". It's very easy to think about differences between vowels as "long" vs "short", between consonants as "voiceless" vs "voiced", once someone has told you about them. The phonetic reality is much more complex. A "short" vowel may actually be even shorter in certain contexts, or just as a long as its "long" counterpart in others.

Comment: @PeterShor (Sorry for the repost, but I just noticed a very bad error in the original) I'm not familiar with "Southern British English", so I can't prove anything. Is it in any way similar to "Received Pronunciation", which is what I meant by "British English"? Of course different dialects have different sets of phonemes, and I don't deny that there may be dialects where /ɛː/ and /ɛ/ actually contrast in length only.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw: the traditional "Received Pronunciation" is now mainly used by older people; the language is changing. "Southern British English" is one name for the pronunciation system that is replacing it (although it's not that big a change). The word *bare* is now apparently pronounced by the majority of younger British English speakers as a long vowel, and not a diphthong. So it's /ɛə/ in RP and it's /ɛː/ in the more modern pronunciation.

Comment: @PeterShor I googled "Southern British English" and got some conflicting results. There's no Wikipedia article specifically about it, only one that covers many different dialects in southern England. I'm not even sure if "Southern British English" is the name of a single, identifiable entity. Could you share your source?

Comment: (1) [This blog post](https://www.englishspeechservices.com/blog/the-demise-of-e%c9%99-as-in-square/) talks about the change in pronunciation of the vowel in SQUSRE from [eə] to [ɛː]. I don't believe the blog post mentions "standard Southern British English", but it is mentioned in other posts on the same blog. (2) Note also that *Lexico* (formerly the *Oxford Dictionary Online*) changed its phonetic symbol for SQUARE from /eə/ to /ɛː/. They did this because the prevailing pronunciation changed from a centering diphthong to a long vowel, with vowel quality very close to the vowel of DRESS.

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw: And [here](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english-uni.htm) is a discussion by renowned phonetician John C. Wells about the pros and cons of switching the IPA symbol from /eə/ to /ɛː/.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for the sources. I vaguely remember Mr. Wells explained the choice of /i/ in his blog, for words like *lady* for example, as a compromise, merely because neither /iː/ nor /ɪ/ feels right. Phonologically, in cases where phonemes are neutralized, you can further abstract them into an archiphoneme which will complicate things, or pick one of them as the "default" phoneme which will simplify things. /i/ proves that there's a lot more to dictionary making than just raw phonological analysis, and what appears to be "phonemic" isn't always straightforward.

Comment: @PeterShor Interesting. According to [this key to the letters](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/key-to-pronunciation), Lexico still labels the pronunciation they represent as "Received Pronunciation", even though they use some unorthodox notations such as /ɛː/, /əː/, /ʌɪ/, and even an acknowledgement of tripthongs, which would be treated as two syllables by other dictionaries. I wonder if this new system is used for the printed Oxford dictionaries too.

Comment: @PeterShor The section "5. Vowels: quantitative and qualitative" of that article by John Wells you referred to explains pretty neatly about the length mark. It's a compromise, and it's "admittedly somewhat redundant" in his own words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, but here's an interesting quote from Abercrombie's book *Fifty years in Phonetics.*

> In America phonetic notation has had a curious history. Bloomfield
>   used  IPA notation in his early book *An Introduction to the Study
>   of Language*, 1914, and in  the English edition of his more famous
>   *Language*, 1935. But since then, a strange  hostility has been
>   shown by many American linguists to IPA notation, especially to
>   certain of its symbols.
>
> An interesting and significant story was once told by Carl Voegelin
>   during a symposium held in  New York in 1952 on the present state of
>   anthropology. He told how, at the  beginning of the 1930s, he was
>   being taught phonetics by, as he put it, a "pleasant Dane", who made
>   him use  the IPA symbol for sh in ship, among others. Some while later
>   he used those symbols in some work  on an American Indian language he
>   had done for Sapir. When Sapir saw the work he "simply blew up", 
>   Voegelin said, and demanded that in future Voegelin should use 's
>   wedge' (as š was called), instead of  the IPA symbol.

When I used this quote in my dissertation, I got the following interesting response from a committee member:

> Sapir probably knew how hard it is to see the difference between esh
>   and s-wedge in handwriting. This is the main reason Howie Aronson
>   cited in a class ... relating it
>   to the tradition of doing fieldwork versus creating nice printed
>   books. Like other IPA propagandists, Abercrombie seems to want to link
>   this to American exceptionalism, infelicitously conflating
>   "Americanist" with "American". Fortunately, you don't use "esh" but,
>   rather, curly-tailed c...

Comment: Personally, I think it's related to the desire to keep monoglot Americans ignorant of the phonetic values of the Latin alphabet in almost all other languages that use it. :) They don’t want people to be confused that we've shifted everything during the Great Vowel Shift so that the letters and sounds no longer match up, like the sound /i/ being what they think of as the letter E not I, or the sound /e/ being what they think of as the letter A not E, or that the name of the letter I is pronounced /ai/ etc. It's so scrambled that this keeps monoglots from pronouncing other languages correctly.

Comment: Whoever came up with that "infelicitous" reasoning seemed to deliberate ignore the fact that the long s, a variant of a regular s, predates printed books and is perfectly legible. The esh is obviously long, and if you can't distinguish between a long character with both an ascender and a descender and a short one with none, the problem lies in either bad handwriting or bad eyesight, not the character itself, which means that it can be easily argued that adding awkward diacritics to smaller set of English letters doesn't improve legibility.

Answer (score 6):

People who say IPA system does not work are just liars. This is not true. I have been teaching English as a Foreign Language for more than 40 years and the improvements in pronunciation are just amazing from the first basic lesson. What English students need are real tools to help them learn by themselves. The International Phonetic Alphabet works and it is easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Pollard is correct regarding the impracticality of the IPA for the overwhelming majority of monoglot speakers of American English. Unlike polyglot Europeans, most Americans are quite content using the simpler systems of phonetic symbols presented in American dictionaries and would not benefit from the investment of time necessary to familiarize themselves with the significantly greater complexity of the IPA. For better or worse, it’s the nature of the dominant culture.

Comment: In my experience, most Americans don't bother learning any system of phonetic symbols, whether IPA or otherwise. And I don't think the non-IPA systems are simpler: you don't have to learn the entire IPA to learn the subset of it that is used to transcribe English.

Comment: As @herisson, I too disagree. All dictionaries I have ever used include an explanation of all the IPA symbols used with example words, e.g.: ‘/ʌː/ as in f*a*ther, /ɔː/ as in l*a*w.’ Explanations are in other words done with words that are well-known even to those who are beginners in the language. There is a reason we learnt IPA for English in primary school; it is a ‘real tool[] to help [us] learn by [our]selves. The International Phonetic Alphabet works and it is easy to learn.’ as mentioned by Enrique Guerra above.

Comment: Look up one word in Merriam-Webster and explain exactly how that jumble of letters with awkward diacritics belongs to a system any "simpler" than IPA. You'll still have to learn the arbitrary rules devised by the dictionary makers, and worse of all, there's no common standard for all dictionaries to follow.

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer the IPA there is the Merriam-Webster Advanced Learner's Dictionary and the online Britannica Dictionary. For those who don't want the IPA there are the other M-W dictionaries and other American dictionaries.
Now, some will argue that the Americans are being perverse, but actually the Americans did some of the earliest major work in this field(Whitney, Hanna and many more) and have always taught the IPA at universities. Another argument is that some will try to over-project the European viewpoint, as for example the treatment of the r-coloured vowels as a contrast or extension to the RP non-rhotic notation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Likely because IPA is a joke. In a standard non translation dictionary (i.e. not french to english) the native english speaker is using the book to conferm spelling and look up meaning. Accent is not a consideration. While written english is non phonetic compared with alphabets that use visual accents, IPA is in itself a separate language that would require lessons to decipher.
Basically, IPA is in no way, shape, or form helpful to people looking for phonetic pronunciation. It's more helpful to break down words into segments and liken the sections to generally understood words or sounds. Best example of this is the Wikipedia entry on "Roosevelt". The IPA would be unhelpful to 99% of people looking it up. Far easier would be "rose-a-velt".

Comment: If pronunciation is "not a consideration" for native English speakers when they look up words in dictionaries, why do dictionaries include pronunciation at all? IPA is in no way "a separate language." It's a separate alphabet, and it's no harder to learn than most foreign alphabets. It's certainly useful for people if the pronunciation resource they're using transcribes words in IPA. Many dictionaries do so, such as the Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: BTW, Mike, do you happen to be American, by any chance?

Comment: "IPA is in itself a separate language that would require lessons to decipher" It's a joke because you have to learn it? Are you kidding me? This entire answer is a complete joke, and it's infuriating that it shows up among my Google search results, instead of the more informed answers above. Who the hell are you to claim that "99% of people" are so stupid that they can only parse the anglocentric "phonetic" spelling "rose-a-velt"? How exactly is it "far easier"? It can just easily be read as "rose AY velt" instead. I implore you, never give an answer again, for the sake of the human race.